# swift code return alert type String not working

Tags: ios, swift

i find void return alert but string alert return not found.
trying Void to String

```
// return Void Alert
func returnAlert(title: String!, message: String! ,success: (() -> Void)? , cancel: (() -> Void)?) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title:title,
            message: "",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        self.newQtyField = UITextField()
        self.newQtyField.keyboardType = .NumberPad

        func addTextField(textField: UITextField!){
            // add the text field and make the result global
            let row = self.array[Int(message)!]
            textField.text = String(row.pbQty!)
            self.newQtyField = textField
        }


        let cancelLocalized = NSLocalizedString("cancel", tableName: "activity", comment:"")
        let okLocalized = NSLocalizedString("ok", tableName: "Localizable", comment:"")

        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelLocalized,
        style: .Cancel) {
            action -> Void in cancel?()
        }
        let successAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: okLocalized,
        style: .Default) {
            action -> Void in success?()
        }
        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(addTextField)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(successAction)


        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

// bottom call fun | i think success: { () to success: { textfield , but not working how... need your help

```
    returnAlert("title", message: "msg", success: { () -> Void in


        })
    { () -> Void in
        print("user canceled")
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to return the text of `newQtyField` when user touch `ok`?

Comment: yes it is!!! it is as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very hard to understand what you are saying in your question.

You should change the method definition to this:

```
func returnAlert(title: String!, message: String! ,success: ((text:String) -> Void)? , cancel: (() -> Void)?) {
```

and change the `successAction` to return the value of the UITextField:

```
let successAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: okLocalized,
            style: .Default) { action in
                success?(text: self.newQtyField.text!)
            }
```